# Pandas custom week

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to define a custom week for a dataframe.

I have a dataframe with timestamps.
I've read the questions on here regarding isocalendar. While it does the job. It's not what I want.

I'm trying to define the weeks from Friday to Thrusday.

For example:

Friday 2nd Jan 2015 would be the first day of the week.

Thursday 8th Jan 2015 would be the last day of the week.

And this would be week 1.

Is there a way to set a custom weekday? so when I access the the `datetime` library, I get the result that I expect.

`df['Week_Number'] = df['Date'].dt.week`

Comment: Have a look at the timestamp offset documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects.  It may help!

Comment: check this @Andy Hayden reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530556/resample-time-series-in-pandas-to-a-weekly-interval/14531149#14531149

Comment: @ Michal Thanks a lot. I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution - convert your dates to a [`Period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#period) representing weeks that end on Thursday.

```
In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2015-1-1', '2015-12-31')})

In [40]: df['Period'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('W-THU')

In [41]: df['Week_Number'] = df['Period'].dt.week

In [44]: df.head()
Out[44]: 
        Date                Period  Week_Number
0 2015-01-01 2014-12-26/2015-01-01            1
1 2015-01-02 2015-01-02/2015-01-08            2
2 2015-01-03 2015-01-02/2015-01-08            2
3 2015-01-04 2015-01-02/2015-01-08            2
4 2015-01-05 2015-01-02/2015-01-08            2
```

Note that it follows the same convention as datetimes, where week 1 can be incomplete, so you may have to do a little extra munging if you want 1 to be the first complete week.